# Efficiency UPDATE WHERE ... vs CASE ... WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the case of a big table (~5 millions lines) what is more efficient to update all lines that matches a condition (circa 1000 rows):

**1.** A simple update statement ?

```
UPDATE table SET last_modif_date = NOW() WHERE condition;
```

**2.** A case when that perform an update if condition matches

```
UPDATE table SET
last_modif_date = (CASE WHEN CONDITION THEN NOW() ELSE last_modif_date END)
```

And why ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No it isn't :) I cannot determine the number of rows in advance but circa 1000 rows

Comment: Why don't you simply test?

Comment: Because i want to know why & also i have not the data yet to test :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a simple test - and the results was that the `where` version is more efficient then the `case` version.
Here is the test I've made:

```
/*

-- Create a numbers (tally) table if you don't already have one
SELECT TOP 10000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number
    INTO Tally
    FROM sys.objects s1       
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2 
ALTER TABLE Tally ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Tally PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)

*/


-- Create a dates table with 10000 rows
SELECT Number As Id, DATEADD(DAY, Number, DATEADD(DAY, -5000, GETDATE())) As TheDate
INTO DatesTest
FROM Tally

-- Update using a where clause 
UPDATE DatesTest 
SET TheDate = GETDATE()
WHERE Id % 100 = 0

-- Drop and re-create the same dates table
DROP TABLE DatesTest

SELECT Number As Id, DATEADD(DAY, Number, DATEADD(DAY, -5000, GETDATE())) As TheDate
INTO DatesTest
FROM Tally

-- Update using case
UPDATE DatesTest 
SET TheDate = CASE WHEN Id % 100 = 0 THEN GETDATE() ELSE TheDate END
```

As you can see from the execution plan - The where clause version is only 7% of all execution cost while the case version is 34%.
I'ld say we have a winner.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A general best practice is not to `update` or `delete` without a `where` clause because people make mistakes and recovering from some of them can be a real pain.

Beyond that, even non-updating updates can have a significant impact on the database beyond just a poor performing query. Executing an `update` without a `where` can also lead to excessive locking and blocking of other concurrent operations.

I can not summarize this article any better than Paul White did for himself, here are some more things to consider:

> SQL Server contains a number of optimisations to avoid unnecessary logging or page flushing when processing an UPDATE operation that will not result in any change to the persistent database.
>
> - Non-updating updates to a clustered table generally avoid extra logging and page flushing, unless a column that forms (part of) the cluster key is affected by the update operation.
> - If any part of the cluster key is ‘updated’ to the same value, the operation is logged as if data had changed, and the affected pages are marked as dirty in the buffer pool.  This is a consequence of the conversion of the UPDATE to a delete-then-insert operation.
> - Heap tables behave the same as clustered tables, except they do not have a cluster key to cause any extra logging or page flushing.  This remains the case even where a non-clustered primary key exists on the heap.  Non-updating updates to a heap therefore generally avoid the extra logging and flushing (but see below).
> - Both heaps and clustered tables will suffer the extra logging and flushing for any row where a LOB column containing more than 8000 bytes of data is updated to the same value using any syntax other than ‘SET column_name = column_name’.
> - Simply enabling either type of row versioning isolation level on a database always causes the extra logging and flushing.  This occurs regardless of the isolation level in effect for the update transaction.
>     ~ [The Impact of Non-Updating Updates - Paul White](http://web.archive.org/web/20180406220621/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The result are just different since the UPDATE SET with CASE will update ALL the rows and will triggers on update and so on EVEN if in your case your new values is in fact the previous value.

The UPDATE with a WHERE clause will UPDATE only the rows you really want to update and trigger only on these rows. Assuming you have an index, it is more efficient in most cases.

The only way for you to be sure is to analyse the actual execution plan of both queries and compare. Anyway the use of an UPDATE SET CASE over UPDATE WHERE is somewhat unnatural.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, 'where' clause would be more efficient than 'Case' statement if you have an index on the column that you are using. 'Case' statement will make the query (search) sequential, meaning that every row will be checked for the condition. Where clause with index on the column (that can be used in the condition that you are applying), will only scan a subset of records and will use faster search algorithm (in most cases).

Bottom line is the actual query(condition that you are using) and the indexes can make a lot of differences in the performance of the statement. The best way to analyse the query, is to use the execution plan of the query in SQL server management studio.

You can read this post to learn more about execution plans:
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/

Comment: So if there is an index use update else prefere using case

Comment: It is not always that black and white. depends on the index and the condition that you are using. For example if the index is on columnA and condition is ColumnA > Value A,index will be used in the query and you will get a better perfomance.

Comment: No it means in case of an index it's more likely to have a WHERE clause more efficient. It doesn't mean CASE is better (it could be worse [or better] with and without an index).